# How to make Web.Config Transform files work during both build & publish?

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, web-config, web-deployment

For web projects, eg. ASP.Net MVC applications I am not able to get my Web.config Transform files to apply during Build/debug locally.

The Transformations don't seem to work when launching from Visual Studio with the Start (play) button. I'd like to be able to do quick switches during development so I can test different databases, and various appsettings.

The Tranform files seem to work perfectly fine only when the application is actually published.

Also, for any of you that use the web.config transform files, what is the best setup?

It seems like I would want to have separate config files for each environment (Development, Testing, and Production). Then I would want to have a Debug & Release version of each config file.. thats means 6 different config files + the default debug & release config files that are baked into VS. That seems like a lot.